# coupled equations with finite difference method

Tags: matlab, computational-physics

I have these three differential equations in which I need to solve numerically:

$$
\frac{dn_0}{dt}= -n_0(t)W_{01}(t) + n_1(t)K_{10}
$$

$$
\frac{dn_1}{dt}= -n_1(t)W_{12}(t) - n_1(t)K_{10} + n_2(t)K_{21} + n_0(t)W_{01}(t)
$$

$$
\frac{dn_2}{dt}= n_1(t)W_{12}(t) - n_2(t)K_{21}
$$

such that

$$ n_0(0)=1 $$
$$ n_0(N)=0 $$
$$ n_1(0)=0 $$
$$ n_1(N)=1 $$
$$ n_2(0)=0 $$
$$ n_2(N)=0 $$

Using the central finite difference formula:

$$\frac{n_{0}(t + \Delta t) - n_{0}(t - \Delta t)}{2\Delta t}=-n_0(t)W_{01}(t) + n_1(t)K_{10}$$

$$\frac{n_{1}(t + \Delta t) - n_{1}(t - \Delta t)}{2\Delta t}=-n_1(t)W_{12}(t) - n_1(t)K_{10} + n_2(t)K_{21} + n_0(t)W_{01}(t)$$

$$\frac{n_{2}(t + \Delta t) - n_{2}(t - \Delta t)}{2\Delta t}=n_1(t)W_{12}(t) - n_2(t)K_{21}
$$

How do I determine the functions $n0$, $n1$ and $n2$ knowing that $n0 + n1 + n2 =1$, and that the three equations are coupled?

And I could not understand how to calculate the derivatives, how can I determine their value with the finite difference method without knowing the functions?

Can someone please help me?

Hmm, so I did it now.

$$ \frac{n_{0_{i+1}} - n_{0_{i-1}}}{2\Delta t}=
-n_0(t_i)W_{01}(t_i) + n_1(t_i)K_{10}$$

with $$ t_i= (i-1)\Delta t $$ and $$ i= 2,3,... N-1 $$ for $$ \Delta t=\frac{b-a}{N-1} $$

knowing that this gives a system of the type $$ Au=B$$
I can not think of a way to fill the array. I say, on the right side of the equation, what values $ n_0(t_i)$ and $n_1(t_i)$ assume as $t_i$  varies?

I tried to implement in scilab, but to no avail

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to think of your coupled equations as one equation.

Be n=$\left(\begin{array}{c}n_0\\n_1\\n_2\end{array}\right)$, you can write it as
$$\frac{d}{dt}n= A n$$ with $$A=\left(\begin{array}{ccc}-W_{01}(t)&K_{10} &0\\W_{01}(t)&-W_{12}(t) - K_{10}&K_{21}\\0&W_{12}(t)&-K_{21}\end{array}\right).$$

For the constraint you could either derive a new set of equations by explicitly  solving the constraint for $n_2=1-n_0-n_1$ and plug it in or if you want to be flexible with linear constraints of such type, you could do the following.

**Linear Constraints**

We can rewrite the linear constraint equation as $$Bn=l$$ with $$B=\left(\begin{array}{ccc}1&1&1\end{array}\right)$$ and $$l=1.$$

Now be $I_B$ a matrix of a basis of the image space of $B$ and $N_B$ a matrix of a basis of the null space of B, we can do a change of basis by writing $n$ as $$n=I_B n_{I}+ N_B n_{N}.$$ The matrices $I_B$ and $N_B$ can be obtained by using a singular value decomposition on $B$. Our new variables are $n_I$ and $n_N$.

Using this basis in the constraint equation leads to $$B I_B n_I+B N_B n_N=l.$$ By construction $B N_B n_N= 0$,  we solve the linear system for $n_I$ $$B I_B n_I =  l.$$

The same basis can be used in the ODE system
$$\frac{d}{dt}\left(I_B n_I + N_B n_N \right)= A \left(I_B n_I + N_B n_N \right)$$
$\frac{d}{dt}I_B n_I=0$ because it is a constant of motion due to the constraint equation.

Now multiplying both sides with $N_B^T$ leads to the reduced final system
$$\frac{d}{dt} n_N = N_B^T A I_B n_I + N_B^T A N_B n_N .$$

You can apply your favorite time integrator on the vectorized version of the equation for the variables $n_N$, since we haven taken care of the constraints. Remember, the first term on the rhs $N_B^T A I_B n_I$ is a known function of $t$, since we solved already for $n_I$.

Once you have obtained a solution for $n_N$, you can use our change of basis to obtain the solution in $n_0$ to $n_2$.

**Time Integration**

The simplest method is for sure the [Euler method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_method), which is in this case leads to $$n_N^{i+1}=n_N^i+\Delta t \left(N_B^T A(t_i) I_B n_I + N_B^T A(t_i) N_B n_N^i\right).$$

Due to the dependency of the next step from the previous one, you cannot simply build up a system and solve it. Additionally, since $W_{01}(t)$ is a function of time, it is possible to a have a stiff or non stiff ODE system. So a recommendation is difficult, a good overview of possible solvers and there application can be found [here](http://diffeq.sciml.ai/latest/solvers/ode_solve.html).

Also you mention too many initial conditions. You only need at one point in time, e.g. the initial conditions at $t=0$, $$n_N(0)=N_B^T\left(\left(\begin{array}{c}n_0(0)\\n_1(0)\\n_2(0)\end{array}\right)-I_B n_I\right).$$

I don't know scilab, but it seems that they have [time integrators for ODEs](https://help.scilab.org/docs/6.0.1/en_US/ode.html), too. So check their documentation how to use them.

Comment: Thank you, and I'm sorry. Due to personal problems I had to leave and I could not thank properly. And I ended up leaving that question aside.

I do not quite understand what you did at the end, what does this term $ N_B ^ T $ mean you multiply on both sides?

Comment: Yes, since $N_B^T N_B=Id$ is the identity matrix, because $N_B$ is a unitary matrix. So you can multiply both sides with this matrix to obtain the equation for $\frac{d}{dt}n_N$. This is useful but not necessary. Because not every ODE solver allows  an additional matrix multiplication on the time derivative vector.